# Constraint name is being ignored

Tags: mysql, constraints

I'm trying to learn the concept of foreign key constraints, and have read the [manual about](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) using these types of constraints. I'm pretty understanding of these constraints, and they work as intended. However the manual says the syntax for creating constraints is `FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)` but when I run the following query, both foreign key constraints gets an entirely different name;

```
CREATE TABLE blog_user (
    `blog` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `user`  INTEGER NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE `blog_user` (`blog`, `user`),

    FOREIGN KEY `blog_reference` (`blog`)
        REFERENCES `blog` (`id`)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,

    FOREIGN KEY `user_reference` (`user`)
        REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Constraint names result in `blog_ibfk_1` instead of `blog_reference` and `user_ibfk_1` instead of `user_reference`. Why do they get their own name, instead of the one I told it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword for specifying the FK constraint like

```
 CONSTRAINT `blog_ibfk_1`  FOREIGN KEY (`blog`)
        REFERENCES `blog` (`id`)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Comment: Thank you, it turns out I didn't quite understand the manual. I thought the constraint name was determined by the `index_name` but in fact it was the `symbol`. Adding the `CONSTRAINT constraint_name` part names them correctly!